# tinymce keyup event doesn't fire on tab key

Tags: jquery, tabs, tinymce, tinymce-4, keyup

I am using tinymce 4.3.2 and I am trying to add a custom event when you press the tab key inside the editor. 
Here's my setup using the jquery plugin:

```
$(el).tinymce({
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        'textcolor'
    ],
    toolbar: 'bold italic underline forecolor',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
            console.log('keyup event fired');
        });
    }
});
```

However, when I press the tab key, this keyup function does not seem to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a lot of time thinking about this, and I hope to save someone from wasting a bunch of time on this. Seemed like the tab would go to the next element before the keyup event was able to be registered. The solution is to add a keydown event and prevent the default if you hit the tab key.

```
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('keydown', function(e) {
        var key = e.keyCode || e.which;

        // do nothing on tab key
        if (key == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

    }).on('keyup', function(e) {
        console.log('keyup event fired');
    });
}
```

success!

Comment: _I spent a lot of time thinking about this_... Looks like about 7 minutes to me :)

Comment: I posted after I figured it out, because I thought it would be helpful :)